# How to pass the object reference of parent User Control to ViewModel using xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a User Control, let's say TextboxPage and it's associated with ViewModel, TextboxPageViewModel. I need to get reference of TextboxPage in TextboxPageViewModel.

i.e.

```
<Button x:Name="btnCustomer" 
Command="{Binding CustomerCommand}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding...?}"/>
```

How can I do binding in xaml to pass the reference of UserControl, TextboxPage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in your case:

```
<Button x:Name="btnCustomer" 
Command="{Binding CustomerCommand}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```

cheers!